# How to use \timing in postgres

Tags: postgresql, psql, timing

I want to know the time that it takes to execute a query in Postgres. I see a lot of answers that suggest to use `\timing`, but I'm newbie in Postgres and I don't know how to use it.

Comment: [here's the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `\timing` only with the command line client `psql`, since this is a `psql` command.

It is a switch that turns execution time reporting on and off:

```
test=> \timing
Timing is on.
test=> SELECT 42;
┌──────────┐
│ ?column? │
├──────────┤
│       42 │
└──────────┘
(1 row)

Time: 0.745 ms
test=> \timing
Timing is off.
```

Comment: ok then if I want to test a select query how i can do that I tried to do what you have done, but instead of `select 42`I do `select * from my_db` and I get `Commande \select invalide.`

Comment: Try `SELECT` instead of `\select`, without the backslash.

Comment: I'm getting a weird error, when a do \dt *.* I get a list that contains `my_schema` and `my_relation` but when I do a `select * from my_schema.my_relation` I get this error: `relation my_schema.my_relation doesn't exist`

Comment: ok I solve it, I had just to use "my_schema"."my_relation", but still a question I want to test the time that takes to response to a query that returns more that 1000000, and I don't think that this option is the best

Comment: If you want to measure the time it takes to output the result to a file, you can use `time` on UNIX like this: `time psql -P pager=off -c 'SELECT ...' >outfile`

Comment: I get this error `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "time"
LIGNE 1 : time psql -P pager=off -c 'select * from "my_schema"."my_relation "`

Comment: Which operating system are you on? Maybe you just have to install `time`.

Comment: I'm using windows7

Comment: That makes things harder. You can execute a batch file with the `psql` command line sandwiched between two `echo %TIME%`. Then a simple subtraction will tell how long it took.

Comment: @aName if you just want to figure out the time a query would take to run, you use "EXPLAIN ANLYZE ... query." which (kind of) really runs the query.

Comment: How to persist this across sessions? I want this to be enabled even after quitting the psql session.

Comment: @Krishna To enable timing for all your `psql` sessions, run this in your shell (note the double backslash): `echo '\\timing on' >> ~/.psqlrc`

Comment: @TimurShtatland thanks a lot. But I switched to `pgcli` long back, which already provides timing along with many other features.